# Attaching click handler on an SVG elment doesn't capture click event on chart background

Tags: svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

Added a click handler on SVG chart (Scatter) that print's a console message.
Expected that this handler will be triggered on clicking anywhere on the chart.

But,click event is triggered only when i click on axis labels & bubbles but not if I click any where on the chart.

Have copied the example `http://nvd3.org/ghpages/scatter.html` to a JSBin

```
http://jsbin.com/elohiv/1/
```

Click on a bubble/axis label and see console message printed showing "click captured".
But clicking anywhere else on the chart doesn't trigger click event.

Can you please suggest what may be blocking the click event to be triggered on clicking an area on chart other than axis labels/bubbles?

Comment: SVG only adds click events for drawn child elements, not the SVG container itself. Notice that your event works for anything within, including all text, lines etc. Why not simply add your click event to the div wrapper that is housing the SVG container?

Comment: Good workaround..tried it and looks working..Thanks!!